Why is this while loop terminating midway?
I am running a while loop for a 'guess the random number' project. My problem is that when the user is finally guessing the right answer, the code below is not printing 'Bingo' as it should. Instead, it is exiting the while loop.
In other languages, the while loop evaluates the conditional after it has run each time. In this case, it appears that the loop is terminating the moment when the conditional is no longer true, even before the last statement has been executed.
Why is this so?
import random
x=100
random_number = random.randint(1,x)
y = int(input('what do you think is the number?! '))
while y!= random_number:
    if y>random_number:
        print('Too high')
        y = int(input('what do you think is the number?! '))
    elif y<random_number:
        print('Too low')
        y = int(input('what do you think is the number?! '))
    else:
        print('Bingo!')


it is because when y=random_number is true the loop terminates. The else block will never execute inside the loop

When the user enters the correct number, the y != random_number condition on the next iteration fails, so the loop stops. It never gets to the else: block.
Instead of while condition:, check the condition inside the loop and use break to stop after printing the message.
while True:
    y = int(input('what do you think is the number?! '))
    if y>random_number:
        print('Too high')
    elif y<random_number:
        print('Too low')
    else:
        print('Bingo!')
        break


@Barmar's answer is right. Another way to do this is to use Python's while...else construct. Using your original code, just unindent the else block:
import random
x=100
random_number = random.randint(1,x)
y = int(input('what do you think is the number?! '))
while y!= random_number:
    if y>random_number:
        print('Too high')
        y = int(input('what do you think is the number?! '))
    elif y<random_number:
        print('Too low')
        y = int(input('what do you think is the number?! '))
else:
    print('Bingo!')

Python allows else after for and while loops, which gets executed when the test fails.
I would still write this the way @Barmar showed, though. I just thought it was interesting that your code would work simply by unindenting one part.

You don't even need the else: line in this case.  Just unindent the print outside the while.
